# ExtJS : Widget Combo resets value for all fields when i click on expand

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6.2

I am using a `treePanel` in which one column is using `widgetColumn` with combo inside cell.

Below is sample code.

```
{
    text: 'TC',
    dataIndex: 'scrTC',
    xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
    widget: {
        xtype: 'combo',
        store: 'TCStore',
        valueField: 'value',
        displayField: 'displayValue',
        matchFieldWidth: false,
    }
}
```

When I change values of combo for few rows & then expand the other children in grid all combo value a reset to default value again.Not sure whats the issue here.

Code for store :

```
Ext.define('TC', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: 'TCStore',
    model: 'CommonModel',
    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'resources/data/tree/TC.json'
    }
});
```

Screenshot of treepanel:

[image: Screenshot of treepanel]

When I click on another children  node, example 3 or 4 it resets the value for all combo in all rows.

Thanks for help.

Code changes after the below answer,
which gives the getRecord undefined error.

```
Ext.define('MyTree', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    reference: 'myTree',
    columns: {

            item:[{
                text: 'TC',
                dataIndex: 'scrTC',
                xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
                widget: {
                    xtype: 'combo',
                    store: 'TCStore',
                    valueField: 'value',
                    displayField: 'displayValue',
                    matchFieldWidth: false,
                    listeners: {
                        change: function (combo) {
                            if (combo.hasFocus) {
                                var treeview = combo.up('myTree'), //myTree is reference of my treepanel
                                    record = treeview.getRecord(combo.el.up('tr')); ///getting error here
                                record.set('scrTC', combo.getValue());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you show in a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution,

```
select: function (combobox, record) {
        combobox.getWidgetRecord().set(combobox.getWidgetColumn().dataIndex, record.data.value);
    }
```

this resolves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the property `dataIndex: 'scrTC'` and you just change the value of your combo not this `scrTC`. When your node expand or collapse, so it again the set the same `scrTC` value.

So you need to change the value of `scrTC`, when you are changing the value of your combo.

You can check here with working **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2l18)**

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'TCStore',
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'TC.json'
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {

            storeId: 'treeStore',

            fields: ['name'],
            root: {
                name: 'Root',
                expanded: true,
                scrTC: 1,
                children: [{
                    name: 'One',
                    scrTC: 2,
                    children: [{
                        name: 'Child 1',
                        scrTC: 3,
                        leaf: true
                    }, {
                        name: 'Child 2',
                        scrTC: 4,
                        leaf: true
                    }]
                }, {
                    name: 'Two',
                    scrTC: 5,
                    leaf: true
                }]
            },

        });

        Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {

            store: 'treeStore',

            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            title: 'Tree Panel Demo',
            columns: {
                defaults: {
                    width: 200
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'treecolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'name'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'scrTC',
                    widget: {
                        xtype: 'combo',
                        store: 'TCStore',
                        valueField: 'value',
                        displayField: 'displayValue',
                        matchFieldWidth: false,
                        listeners: {
                            change: function (combo) {
                                if (combo.hasFocus) {
                                    var record = combo.getWidgetRecord(),
                                        property = combo.getWidgetColumn().dataIndex;

                                    record.set(property, combo.getValue());
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried fiddle but when i run i dont see any output, also made changes in my code & i am getting error as "treeview.getRecord is not a function"

Comment: May be you have missed something in your code. Can you post your code ? just also check in your code this`treeview = combo.up('treeview')` is available of not.

Comment: the line above returns undefined, so i used combo.up('myTree') -- which is reference to my treepanel.

Comment: you need to change this `combo.up('myTree')` with this `combo.up('treeview')`. Because `treecview` is particular row. Sure it will work

Comment: sadly that doesnt works in my case, it comes as undefined.

Comment: Inside of your `treepanel` instead of  `item` use `items` and also try to compare what you have missed. Because if your using same and same version then I don't think it will undefined.

Comment: sorry for the typo, its 'items'  in actual code and version that i am using is - Sencha Cmd v6.5.3.6

Comment: and what is framework version ?I have also checked in 6.5 as well is working fine.

Comment: version is 6.0.2.437  i tried with this version in fiddle & its not working

Comment: I have also tried with `6.0.2.437` version it's working. now you just put you all efforts in [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor). So if I will get any issue I will resolve

Comment: thanks @Narendra Jadhav for your help, i gave me direction & now i have solution. 
Now I have issue with - after saving data combobox doesnt reset to readaOnly(true) it stay editable. Tried binding it but didnt worked, any idea about same?

Comment: yes.. i have used bind property but when i click on edit n set combo readOnly-false then it makes all the comboboxes as readOnly False.